# OpenSCAP remediation won't boot

Tags: centos6, openscap

I am runnnig OenSCAP on a CentOS 6.9 box, after I run it and remediate the findings my machine won't boot.  It gets to the CentOS splash screen and stops.  When I hit Alt+d it will loop when loading the mouse.  If I remove the mouse it stops after certmonger and just sits there.  I am in the process of narrowing it down but if there's a quick answer that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add which profile you remedied against, and possibly whether the machine remedied was fresh install or some long running heavily customized box?

If you can try again (that is - revert / install again), try latest upstream profiles found on github project release page [1] instead. Version 0.1.28 released as part of CentOS 6.9 is quite an oldie, and possibly even a bit broken. New versions should be in much better shape. (Lots of parts are shared between RHEL6/RHEL7 products, so RHEL6 benefits from RHEL7 development)

[1] https://github.com/OpenSCAP/scap-security-guide/releases